# Prevent thin pizza dough sticking

Tags: pizza, dough

Last time I made Pizza I used the same recipe as always to make the dough, but this time I rolled out the dough really thin to get a nice thin pizza.

As I put the pizza in the over I thought, "this is the best looking pizza *ever* made", but was massively dissapointed 7 minutes later when I was struggling to get the pizza off of my pizza tray. It was completely stuck to the tray.

So, when rolling out a really thin crust pizza, what can be done to prevent it sticking to its cooking surface?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has basically already been answered, but: cornmeal on your cooking surface, cornmeal underneath when you spin out (don't roll; a quick look through all the recent pizza questions will find you my answer on how to shape your dough) your base.

Comment: OK, so should I be putting cornmeal on the surface on which the pizza cooks?

Comment: You can also use parchment paper.

Comment: Parchment is inferior for the purpose, to say nothing of the environmental consequences of silicone-impregnated paper over perfectly edible cornmeal.

Comment: Parchment paper is rated for no more than certain temperatures - Reynolds, for instance is 420 degrees F. Assuming you're cooking pizzas at 500+, it would scorch badly, possibly burn.

Comment: I've used parchment to make my last 2 batches of pizza, for a total of 6 pies. It worked amazingly well. I was worried about exceeding the 420F rating listed on the box, but I noticed the paper directly under the dough stays white, whereas the paper sticking out beyond the pie was browned - but not black, not burnt, and didn't smell funny. I used a 550F oven with a pizza stone.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the points in daniel's answer, I'd suggest that if you like good homemade pizza, you should invest in a pizza stone. Not only do they lower the likelihood of the pizza sticking, they also give a much crisper, more authentic base. There are decent ones on Amazon for next to nothing.

Comment: As per Nathan Myhrvold's new tome unless you have 50Kg of steel, or the equivalent in stone, you won't get much more authentic